# Socket error 10013 when sending a Net.Mail via Gmail SMTP in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, email, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to send an e-mail using C# (.NET Framework 4.5) and the System.Net.Mail class via GMail SMTP server, but I always get a

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException "*Failure sending mail.*",

which has an inner System.Web.Exception

> "*Unable to connect to the remote server*", which also has an inner
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException "*An attempt was made to access a
>   socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
>   74.125.113.109:587*" (Socket error code = 10013).

I read a lot of other questions and answers from StackOverflow and other forums about sending e-mails via GMail, including the GMail SMTP info page. I also used the TCPVIEW utility to check if another application has opened the same remote address and port, and I executed my application with administrative rights, and I closed my Outlook client too... and I couldn't solve the problem.

Can you help me?

The piece of code I wrote is here:

```
try 
{           
    using (SmtpClient servidor = new SmtpClient())
    {
        if (servidor == null)
            return false;

        servidor.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        servidor.Port = 587;
        servidor.EnableSsl = true;
        servidor.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        servidor.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("miUser@gmail.com", "miPassword");

        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            if (mail == null)
                return false;

            String de = "miUser@gmail.com";
            mail.From = new MailAddress(de);

            String para = "toMailAddress@xxxx.yyy";
            mail.To.Add(para);

            mail.Subject = "Mail subject";
            mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            mail.Body = "Mail body";
            mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = false;

            mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

            try
            {
                servidor.Send(mail);

                // Alternatively I tried this:
                // servidor.Send(de, para, mail.Subject, mail.Body);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception mex)
{
    return false;
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's not a gmail error that's an SMTP error have you tired searching on System.Net.Mail.SmtpException "Failure sending mail.",

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to tell me. If you ask to me if I checked the SmtpException documentation, the answer is yes.

Comment: I'm trying with other SMTP servers, with no results. For example, using smtp.mail.yahoo.com on port 465 with no SSL I get an inner System.IO.IOException "Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed." after a while. On port 587 with SSL I get the same error as using GMail on the same port: "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 98.139.211.125:587"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625391/system-net-mail-smtpexception-failure-sending-mail